# PowerShell Search-Mailbox Search Query Troubles

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Attempting my hand at some PowerShell scripting. I would like to remove Voice Messages from Inbox's after a certain period of time. The code gets all mailboxes within an organization and pipes them to a Search-Mailbox. Then I need to query the mailboxes using the `-searchquery` option. It does not seem to like how I am placing the Date variable into the query.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-19)
$Test = $Date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
$SB = [scriptblock]::create("Sent: $Test AND Attachment:`"VoiceMessage.wav`"")
Get-Mailbox | Search-Mailbox -TargetMailbox "Example" -TargetFolder "Searching" -SearchQuery $SB -LogOnly -LogLevel Full
```

Edit 1: PowerShell is stating the following when the script is executed:

> Search-Mailbox : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters
>   for the command either because the command does not take pipeline
>   input or the input and its properties do not match any of the
>   parameters that take pipeline input. At line:3 Char:25

Edit Two: Adjusted the Code in my question to the code that works. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot faster to target the Voice Mail search folders?

Comment: I will not argue with that point because it is true that it would be faster. However, the goal here is to find voicemails that were sent X amount of days ago and delete them. Once I have that part tackled, I can look into getting a Voicemail Search Folder out to the masses.

Comment: If the mailbox is UM-enabled, they should already have it.

Comment: I apologize, its an external source sending the voicemails, UM is not enabled in this scenario. I will be keeping search folders in mind though thanks to you. :)

Comment: In your `-SearchQuery` the variable `$Date2` is not expanding as you have the entire query in single quotes. Also the single quotes are not escaped inside so it is terminating early

Comment: Forgive me as I am new to PowerShell. I researched escape characters trying to find the proper way to use the ", ' and ` characters. If I use any other format, PowerShell thinks my variable is a part of my literal string and does not expand either. Is there a specific Syntax to point out variables in strings?

Comment: The " is preferable to ' if you want to use variables inside quotes. See [about_quoting_rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-SearchQuery` syntax is a little off according to the [Message Properties and Search Operators for In-Place eDiscovery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774955(v=exchg.150).aspx)(a fairly small subset of [Message Properties Indexed by Exchange Search](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj983804(v=exchg.150).aspx)).

> Use syntax that matches the property:value format. Values are not case-sensitive, and they can’t have a space after the operator. If there is a space, your intended value will just be full-text searched. For example to: pilarp searches for "pilarp" as a keyword, rather than for messages that were sent to pilarp.

Reducing the quotes that aren't absolutely required will help avoid needing to escape them. It also supports other operators for comparing things like dates.
Try this for the `-SearchQuery`:

```
"Attachment:VoiceMessage.wav AND Received<=$Date2"
```

One thing to note on my own tenant `Search-Mailbox` wouldn't search the attachments at all, despite Attachment being a "supported" key word for `New-MailboxSearch`. I had to resort to finding words in the body to get desired reults. I did wait a few hours to see if it might be slow indexing, but nothing changed. Perhaps you will have better luck.

On another note [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459253(v=exchg.150).aspx) mentions:

> If the mailbox from which you want to delete messages has single item
>   recovery enabled, you must first disable the feature.

That is NOT an absolute requirement. Without turning that off, users may be able to recover the voicemail. Probably not a big deal for your situation.

Comment: I minimized how many quotations I was doing and that seems to help with the variable being accepted. There are some other things stopping this from running and I will update the original code when I get things working properly.