# Junk E-mail Exchange 2010 auto-delete messages older than X days in folder in OWA

Tags: powershell, vbscript

How can I auto delete Junk E-mail folder Exchange 2010 in OWA if I have Exchange 2010 Standard license and standard license CALs?

Custom retention policy tags won't work because it needs Exchange Enterprise license and CALs.
Currently I use this command, but I need to script the command to delete messages from a specific folder in OWA.

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity User -SearchQuery "Subject:'*[Spam]' sent:<$("10.06.2016")" -Delet
eContent -confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-Mailbox` to pass mailbox identities to the `Search-Mailbox` command similar to the way described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779876/powershell-search-mailbox-search-query-troubles). Ex:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "Subject:'*[Spam]' sent:<$("10.06.2016")" -LogOnly -LogLevel Full
```

There are a few things to keep in mind when using `Search-Mailbox` this way. It can't search JUST the spam folder, so test your queries using the `-LogOnly` switch.  You may want to further limit the kind of mailboxes retrieved by using `-RecipientTypeDetails` to retrieve only UserMailbox types. Regardless of what you're trying to delete, be sure you are getting only the results you want from your query before pulling the trigger on `-DeleteContent`.

Comment: How to specify a folder from which to delete messages in Exchange ?

Comment: @KAIIYCTA According to the [Exchange 2010 AQS syntax page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232132%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx#AQS), "folder" or "kind" isn't one of the options. Even then, `Search-Mailbox` can't reliably use every property. Your best bet would be to check the retention policy tag that's applied to the junk mail folder and try the "retentionpolicy" property. Unfortunately, I don't have an Exchange 2010 tenant left to try it with. I'm "stuck" with Exchange 2013 now. Otherwise, just be very, very, careful with the search syntax. Validate before deleting, just to be safe.